# Powershell, Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable with wildcard in ProviderName, no event found

Tags: powershell

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ Providername='MSExchangeIS'; StartTime='2024/03/04'; id=1040 } -MaxEvents 1
```

returns 1 event.

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ Providername='MSExchange*'; StartTime='2024/03/04'; id=1040 } -MaxEvents 1
```

raises the `NoMatchingEventsFound` exception.

```
Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ Providername='MSExchange*'; StartTim ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

the very same requests in `-Verbose` mode

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ Providername='MSExchange*'; StartTime='2024/03/04'; id=1040 } -MaxEvents 1 -Verbose
```

shows that `Get-WinEvent` finds a long list of `Provider` in 3 different `Log`, creates a `QueryList` containing 3 `Query` (one per `Log`, the one for the `Application` `Log` being the largest with 138 `Providers`)

at first I thought that the culprit was the count of `Provider` but the following less restrictive query (without the filter on `id`) returns an event...

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ Providername='MSExchange*'; StartTime='2024/03/04' } -MaxEvents 1
```

is there a documented, or a de facto observed limit on what can be asked to `Get-WinEvent`?

**context**

```
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.6343
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.6343
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

on `Windows 2016`

Comment: Seems a bit odd. Have you considered just qualifying the possible ProviderName's before the query? `$providerlist = (Get-WinEvent -ListProvider MSExchange*).Name; Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ Providername=$providerlist; StartTime='2024/03/04'; id=1040 } -MaxEvents 1`

Comment: Can you show the event?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you explicitly specify the log channel? eg. `-FilterHashtable @{ LogName='<NameOfLogWithMatchingEvent>'; ProviderName='MSExchange*'; ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ultimately, the culprit is the number of providers, but not alone. it has an accomplice.

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ ProviderName = 'MSExchange*'; LogName = 'Application'}
```

raises

```
Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
+ Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ ProviderName = 'MSExcha ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

which is obviously wrong.

If I add `-Verbose` to get the resulant XML `QueryList` and use it in a request

```powershell
$xmlQuery = @'
<QueryList>
    <Query Id="0" Path="application">
        <Select Path="application">
            *[System/Provider[
                @Name="msexchange activesync" or
(138 more @Name= "..." lines)
                @Name="msexchangeweb"
            ]]
        </Select>
    </Query>
</QueryList>
'@

Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXML $xmlQuery
```

the error is now

```
Get-WinEvent : The specified query is invalid
+ Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXML $xmlQuery
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

more testing show that the limit is about 22 or 23 `Provider`, either programtically or in EventViewer.

but why the very same query done with `-FilterXML` and with `-FilterHashtable` does not raise the same error? here enters the accomplice, `logQuery.TolerateQueryErrors = true;` in [the source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics/GetEventCommand.cs#L727) of `Get-WinEvent`.

for some unknown reason, the author of the `Cmdlet` allows a request to silently fail and return nothing instead of raising an error when the request is done via `-FilterHashtable`

OK. but why does

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ ProviderName = 'MSExchange*' }
```

returns 1 event ?

because `MSExchange*` `Providers` write their events not only in the `Application` Log, and the XML resultant `QueryList` becomes

```xml
<QueryList>
    <Query Id="0" Path="application">
        <Select Path="application">
            *[System/Provider[
                @Name="msexchange activesync" or
(138 more @Name= "..." lines)
                @Name="msexchangeweb"
            ]]
        </Select>
    </Query>
    <Query Id="1" Path="msexchange management">
        <Select Path="msexchange management">
            *[System/Provider[
                @Name='msexchange client diagnostics module' or
                @Name='msexchange cmdletlogs' or
                @Name='msexchange configuration cmdlet - management console' or
                @Name='msexchange error logging module' or
                @Name='msexchange management'
            ]]
        </Select>
    </Query>
    <Query Id="2" Path="system">
        <Select Path="system">
            *[System/Provider[
                @Name='msexchange server'
            ]]
        </Select>
    </Query>
</QueryList>
```

`Query Id="0"` still silently fails, but `Query Id="1"` or `Query Id="2"` succeeds and return an event.

in the same way, both

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ ProviderName = 'MSExchange*'; StartDate = '2024/03/08' }
```

and

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ ProviderName = 'MSExchange*'; Id = 1040 }
```

raises

```
Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
+ Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashTable @{ ProviderName = 'MSExcha ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

as `Query Id="0"` still silently fails, and neither `Query Id="1"` nor `Query Id="2"` find event after `2024/03/08` or with `Id=1040`

Comment: At least this gives a '445 limit' error message in powershell 7 `get-winevent -ListLog * | get-winevent`.

Comment: I can get 792 of them this way `get-winevent -ProviderName $prov[0..791].name`.

Comment: @js2010 ```Get-WinEvent -ProviderName``` also generate a multi-```Query``` ```QueryList``` (checked with ```-Verbose```) and also set ```logQuery.TolerateQueryErrors = true;```. so if you add an ```FilterXPath``` to the query, you can bump into the same problem.